# JSON file not being loaded because of not defined variable

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a a python script which is being fed and executed from a html file. This script writes a json file and i'd like to read the json file with javascript. The values are definetely being passed from html to python and they are being processed correctly.

As soon as I want to load the json-file the web console throws an error saying "data is not defined".

The relevant python code:

```
    data = {}
    for i in range(t_final.size):
        data[i] = t_final[i]

    with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
```

Javascript call:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cgi-bin/data.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
            function load() {
                 var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
                 var div = document.getElementById('xbtn');

             }
    </script>
    <div id="xbtn"></div>
```

This is what the json-file contains after executing

```
    {"0": 0.0, "1": 0.013508013525931116, ... , "1999": -0.0}
```

I am working on this for days now and maybe I just don't see it. I presume it is something very obvious.

thanks for any help.

Comment: It won't work to load a JSON file as JavaScript source (via the `<script>` tag as you've done). It will be parsed and the value will be ignored.

Comment: Either you need to declare it was a variable inside the it a script `var data = {"0": ....`, or you need to load it with Ajax.

Comment: Load your data using Ajax, then use it.

Comment: @Striped. Thanks. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

So. I have managed to set up ajax properly. The problem was that the endpoint was set wrong (obviously). So the data to be processed was sent to the json-file and not to the python script where it is supposed to be processed.

The ajax:

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn2').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://192.168.80.27/cgi-bin/verlauf_Grenzen.py',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('.senddata').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        window.alert("Data sent!");
         },
      });
   });
});
```

the HTML:

```
<form class="senddata" method="POST" name="getdata1">
<input id = "testa1" type = "number" step=0.01 name = "a1" />
<input id = "testv1" type = "number" step=0.01 name = "v1" />
<input id = "tests1" type = "number" step=0.01 name = "s1" />
<input id = "testj1" type = "number" step=0.01 name = "j1" />
</form>

<input id="btn2" class="button" type="button" value="Send Values"  value="Click"/>
```

This sends the form elements to the python script.